# Separate Xdebug from php-fpm and nginx containers

Tags: php, docker, nginx, xdebug, devops

I wanted to separate all my development tools from the main php-fpm and nginx containers. So I have basically 3 containers named as **php-fpm** runs on port 9000, **nginx** on port 80 and **dev-tools**. I have installed xdebug, composer etc on my dev-tools container but I am confused how to configure xdebug so that it will work with php-fpm container and can debug my website ? Second question does xdebug need php-cli or php-fpm to run itself?

**#dev-tools**

```
FROM php:7.2-cli-alpine

# Install the PHP extensions we need
RUN set -ex \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- --filename=composer.phar \
    && apk add --no-cache git \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

Comment: I believe xdebug has to be in your *php-fpm* container to allow you to debug your web apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xdebug uses port `9000` by default, which conflicts with the PHP-FPM port.

You would need to change the assigned port of your PHP-FPM pool config or xdebug in php.ini. I recommend updating your PHP-FPM configuration to listen on a different port as it is less to configure for debugging with xdebug.

If you would like to change the port in PHP-FPM.

**/php-fpm.d/pool.conf**

```
[pool]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
```

*Update your NGINX configuration appropriately to use the new port.*

Otherwise if you would like to change the xdebug port in PHP.

**php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

*Update your debugging (PHP editor/IDE) software and firewall configuration to the new port. Alternatively use an SSH tunnel to forward the new remote port 9001 to the default local port 9000*

---

As to your second question

xdebug only runs as an extension of PHP (php-fpm), if it is set to load in your PHP ini settings. It does not run as a separate background service.

Example:

```
[Browser Client -> http://example.com/path/to/script.php] 
   in -> [NGINX] 
        in -> [php-fpm /path/to/script.php] 
[xdebug remote host:port] <- out
```

or

```
[terminal command line] 
    in -> [php /path/to/script.php] 
[xdebug remote host:port] <-out
```

So yes, xdebug needs php-fpm or php-cli to run as they are one and the same.

If through Apache/NGINX that uses php-fpm, it will need to be loaded in your fpm configuration. If through the CLI interface, it would need to be loaded in your CLI configuration.

Keep in mind that you can run PHP with differing ini configurations based on environment. See [PHP - The configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Comment: thanks for your help. I am going to configure it now. Can you please make it clear in which container I should edit the php.ini file and insert the line "xdebug.remote_port=9001" . Should it be inside php-fpm or dev-tools container ? Because I have installed xdebug on dev-tools container.

Comment: As containers `run as isolated processes` If you are running the site through `php-fpm` and want to debug it using `xdebug`, It would need configured in your #php-fpm container.  And the `xdebug` extension would also need to be accessible from your #php-fpm container. As per my examples on how xdebug is run `php-fpm -> xdebug`. If you are running the site in your #dev-tools container, the same applies.

Comment: Are you also missing one key inside xdebug.ini i.e `xdebug.remote_host=dev_tools` . Please correct me if I am wrong. Because I am doubtful how php-fpm knows where to route next as per NGINX -> php-fpm -> xdebug ?

Comment: `xdebug` sends it's data to the specified `xdebug.remote_host`, by default it is `localhost`, it does not bubble up or run as a separate service like php-fpm or nginx. It runs directly through and by the instance of PHP that is executed. I only explained how to fix the issue of port conflict with the default configurations. I do not know your docker network configuration, but in the method you are using, you would want to use an SSH tunnel so `xdebug.remote_host` would be left as default.

Comment: As per the documentation https://xdebug.org/docs/remote  remote_host is where the debug client is running. Can you please tell me which one is `debug client` ? Is it the ip of the system where xdebug extension has been installed or the ip of the container where xdebug has been installed ?

Comment: Your debug client would be your local machine, which is running an IDE that is expecting to receive the remote `xdebug` data. You can also specify your local machine IP address on the same subnet as your web server. Say if your webserver is `192.168.56.100` and your local machine is set to `192.168.56.1` you would set `xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.56.1`, but you would need to set a firewall rule to allow incoming TCP/UDP from the `192.168.56.100` on port `9001` Otherwise you would use an SSH tunnel to capture `remote localhost:9001` and forward it to your `local localhost:9000`

Comment: Apart from it my biggest confusion is How php-fpm talks to Xdebug ?  You told that I have to insert  `xdebug.remote_port=9001`. As per my understanding  it means Xdebug will talk to local browser extension over port 9001.  But how Php-fpm knocks to Xdebug ? How do I say Php-fpm to route the script to xdebug ?

Comment: `php-fpm` is PHP as a CGI process. `xdebug` does not *send data/talk to* php-fpm, php-fpm includes `xdebug` when it is initiated. Which should be enabled by `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` Which adds `extension=xdebug.so` to php.ini.. xdebug then acts as an extra layer within php, as the php reads your script(s). `xdebug` is not a service that runs in the background, it is an extension that is run by php. When xdebug is enabled, using `php -m` from the CLI, will list `xdebug`  Otherwise running a script that has`<?php phpinfo();` should list `xdebug` is an included extension.

Comment: Why I am asking about the connection between php-fpm->xdebug is while I installed xdebug on a separate container I inserted the line  `zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so" ` inside the php.ini file of dev-tools. Please note /usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so is only exist on dev-tools container not inside the php-fpm container.

Comment: @SkyRar Please read Xdebug docs: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote -- "Communication Set-up" section in particular.

Comment: @SkyRar As per my first comment, you must install xdebug with php-fpm, so that php-fpm can include it as an extension. It will not be available to php-fpm and the #php-fpm container from #dev-tools container. Which is why the documentation @LazyOne referenced shows a single box as `[PHP/xdebug]` they are one and the same.

Comment: @fyrye Okay I got it know. So if you are very sure that php-fpm and xdebug can't be run in separate containers then you can edit your answer with this line as the question was to separate the dev tools from php-fpm container.

Comment: @SkyRar clarified my original answer to your second question, *xdebug only runs as an extension of PHP, if it is set to load in your PHP ini settings*.. vs *xdebug runs per request when PHP is executed*